# Send bulk emails in Django with the same attachment

Tags: python, django, email, bulk-email

I want to send emails to members of my site who are to attend a meeting (ie. guests), each with (the same) PDF attachment. I'm doing this with Django's built-in bulk email functionality, in `connection.send_messages(messages)`. At the moment I'm doing this:

```
guests = Guest.objects.all()
connection = mail.get_connection()
connection.open()
messages = []
for guest in guests:
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(title, text_content, from_address, [guest.email], connection=connection)
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')
    pdf_data = open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'uploads/flyer.pdf'))
    msg.attach('Invitation Card.pdf', pdf_data.read(), 'application/pdf')
    pdf_data.close()
    messages.append(msg)
connection.send_messages(messages)
connection.close()
```

Now, when I do it like this, the same PDF file will be loaded for every email, attached separately, and then sent separately for each email, as if it were different PDFs. If the file is 10MB, that 10MB will be uploaded to my mail server for every single guest, where it could have been only once.

**So the question is**: Is it possible to attach a file to all emails at once, thereby also only uploading it once? Or am I just plain doing it wrong?

**UPDATE**:

If I change the attach line to the following:

```
msg.attach_file(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'uploads/flyer.pdf'))
```

would that solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at django/core/mail/message.py reveals `attach_file` is merely a convenience function that opens the file for you before calling `attach`:

```
def attach_file(self, path, mimetype=None):
    """Attaches a file from the filesystem."""
    filename = os.path.basename(path)
    content = open(path, 'rb').read()
    self.attach(filename, content, mimetype)
```

You could avoid opening the attachment and reading it into memory over and over again if you subclass `EmailMultiAlternatives` and override the `attach` method. You should look into using a job/task queue for this like [celery](http://celeryproject.org/docs/django-celery/).

Comment: Hmm, ok. Thanks for looking, I was just too lazy to open it up myself :) Can you think of any way around this problem though?

Comment: No, but you might want to consider using a link rather than an actual attachment.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really an option in this case :(

Comment: You should think about using celery, it's integration with django is really great. It'd be easy to spin up your batch-emailing as a task and do it asynchronously on a worker (or break it down and use multiple workers).

Comment: Mmm, yes, good idea. I've had trouble getting celery to work on Webfaction in the past (and ended up using python threads where necessary), but perhaps this is the time where I need to finally sit down and figure it out. Either that, or write some custom emailing functionality, apparently.